# Wix Local Settings\App Data Shortcut

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, shortcut

How can I create a shortcut using Wix with a target of "%UserProfile%\Local Settings\Application Data\Foo\Logs"?

```
<Shortcut Id="LogsStartMenuShortcut"
  Name="Logs"
  Target="%UserProfile%\Local Settings\Application Data\FalconMobileServer\"
  Icon="icon.ico"/>
```

It doesn't like the % signs in the target.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out this site listing all the [MSI-predefined directories](http://kb.acresso.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q105880) - I would think you should find the one you're looking for in there somewhere :-)

This one here possibly?

`LocalAppDataFolder` Full path to the directory that serves as a data repository for local (non-roaming) applications.